# Can anyone help me what is wrong in my code?

Tags: python

```
def ordered_search(index, ranks, keyword):
    x = index[keyword]
    return order(x, ranks)

def order(x, ranks):
    if len(x)<2 or not x:
        return x
    else:
        l = []
        r = []
        for y in x:
            if ranks[y] > ranks[x[0]]:
                l.append(y)
            else:
                r.append(y)
        return order(l, ranks) + order(r,ranks)`
```

Comment: Do you know what recursion is? If not I encourage you to google it or read this article: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57243/resources-for-improving-your-comprehension-of-recursion

Comment: what are you intpus? what are the expected outputs? what is actually happening? any error? something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your input.

If, in one call to `order`, `x[0]` is the biggest item by `ranks`, you get all the items in the list copied to `r`, and you're calling `order` with exactly the same arguments again. This causes an infinite recursion and at some point (level 1000) it triggers Python's max recursion error.

Try excluding `x[0]` by `for y in x[1:]` and inserting `x[0]` into the results.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot that make sense